# How to customize actionbar navigate home button

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

```
  <style name="MyActionBar.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_style</item>
       <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
   </style>
```

The upper one is default , when i clicked it's background color seem like it. But i want it's background seems like as second.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi check this ActionBar Style Generator in Github  [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100) . Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_style</item> after i add this it happened